# Windows Server AppFabric and services with no .svc file

Tags: c#, iis, appfabric

Is there a way to host a service in Windows Server AppFabric if I use the web.config method of listing the service (so that there is no .svc file)?  On my first try, the AppFabric IIS Snap-in did not list the service.  Is that a limitation, or is there something else that I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You might try routing from Global.aspx. This is how the [.NET REST template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd/) does it.